# Call Local Software With Javascript

Tags: javascript, request, uri, obsidian

There is a software called obsidian which lets you call certain functions that it offers by using urls. So if I type the following command in the browser for example obsidian://advanced-uri?vault=Test&filepath=Test&data=Test , it would create a note with that name. I want to do this programmatically with Pure Javascript(as a Userscript). I have found one way to do it, by using

```
window.open(url)
```

But for this to work I have to disable block up pops for that site. Is there a different way to achieve this(so to call an internal url?). I have tried to do a, get and post request but both gave me a CORS error.

Comment: `window.location = url`